# ElasticSearch Reverse Wildcard Search

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch v5.2.2 I can search for "Jo*" using Wildcard and it will match the index value containing "Joseph"

But what if my index also has these values "Joseph","Jo", "Jos", "Jose" and "Josep" and I want to reverse the query.

How can I find "Jo", "Jos", "Jose" and "Josep" in the index using the string "Joseph" as search criteria?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Do you have any specific analyzer settings in your index right now? If yes, can you share them?

Comment: we didnt add anything special yet, we finally got our documents indexing using NEST yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's possible, but you need to create an `edgeNGram` search analyzer in your index settings.

First create the settings like this. The `name` field will be indexed with the `standard` analyzer but searched with your custom `prefix_search` analyzer instead.

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "prefix_search": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "prefix"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "prefix": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "standard",
          "search_analyzer": "prefix_search"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then if you create a document like this:

```
PUT test/doc/1
{
   "name": "Jos"
}
```

You can find it with a query like this one:

```
POST /test/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "Joseph"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million, Val!

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned....will it also work if i make a query with "aaajoseph" ?

Comment: It works if you replace `edgeNGram` with `nGram` instead. But be aware that you might get all sorts of unrelated results since you're matching on many more tokens.